# How do I embed a response? Discord Bot Python

Tags: python, discord, bots

This is the code I have and I was wondering how do I make it so that the bot embeds the requirements.

```
@client.command()
async def partner(ctx):
    await ctx.send("""__Requirements:__
1)
2)
    """)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```py
@client.command()
async def partner(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Requirements:")
  embed.add_field(name="(1) Title", value="Body 1", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="(2) Title", value="Body 2", inline=False)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the colour of the embed?

Comment: `discord.Embed(..., color=0x00ff00)`